# Error in the ReactJS code? "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at Object.exports.BIG5_CHINESE_CI.”

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to store the username and password entered by the user into mysql database using node.js. The front end is in React.js.
 The following code I have:
    Login.html:

```
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Login</title>


   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "root"></div>
       <script src = "BundleLogin.js"></div>
    </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

LoginClass.js

```
import React from 'react';
import mysql from 'mysql';

require('./stylecs.css');
//ar express    = require("express");

//var mysql      = require('mysql');

class LoginClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      text:
          {
            username:'',
            password:'',
          },
       valid:true,
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(property, event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const text = this.state.text;
      text[property] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({text: text});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {


     if(("Malathi".localeCompare(this.state.text.username) == 0) && ("Tryanuka".localeCompare(this.state.text.password)==0) )

        alert('You are a valid user.\n Sign in details: \nUser Name:' + this.state.text.username 
           +'\nPassword :' + this.state.text.password );
    else
      alert('Username or Password are incorrect.');




  }

  handleFocus()
  {
    this.setState({valid:false});
  }

  validateEmail(event) 
  {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (this.state.valid && !filter.test(this.state.text.username)) 
    {
       return (
          <div>
            <label className="error">Please enter valid email.</label>
          </div>
        );
     }
  }

  handleReset(event)
  {
      this.setState( 
      {
          text:
          {
              username:'',
              password:'',
          }          
      });
  }

   render() {

      return (
           <div className = "mainbox"><br/>
              <div className="heading"> Login Page</div>

              <div className="calign">
                <input className="tbox" type="text"  placeholder="Name" 
                value={this.state.text.username}
               onFocus= {this.handleFocus}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'username')} /> 

              {this.validateEmail(this.state.text.username)}
                </div> 
              <br/>
              <div className="calign">
                  <input className="tbox" type="password"  placeholder="Password" 
                  value={this.state.text.password}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')}/>                    
                   <br/><br/>
                </div>  

              <div className="calign"> 
                  <button className ="btn" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Sign in</button>

                  <button className ="btn" onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button><br/>
                  <a href="/forgot.html">Forgot?</a>
              </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginClass;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "hrportal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Login.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": " webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.12.0",
    "node-mysql": "^0.4.2",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-input-link": "0.0.5",
    "react-popup": "^0.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-validation": "^2.10.9",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.in

```
var config = {
   entry: './LoginMain.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'BundleLogin.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['latest', 'react','es2015']
            }
         },

          {
            test: /\.css?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
          },
       ]
   },

externals: {
    'react': 'React'
},
   target: 'node',


}
module.exports = config;
```

[image: Error screen shot]

I want to store the data from react to mysql using node.js. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I see you have `css-loader` in your webpack config; instead of `require`,  you could `import` the css file. Something like `import styles from './stylecs.css';` and then use classnames as `styles.mainbox` etc.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested. It raised a syntax error. Moreover it is raising the error when I add the statement "import mysql from 'mysql';" to get mysql components. Otherwise it works fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What was the syntax error? and also what's the error you got when you tried `import mysql from 'mysql';`? Post it, let's see if we can debug.

Comment: Its showing syntax error at styles.mainbox.

Comment: But that's legit right? What about the `import mysql` error?

Comment: My goal is to store and retrieve data using react js (UI), node js (server), and MySQL (database) by using webpack.
Appreciate if you have any example along with above functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any examples in hand. May be you can ask another question with your current code setup using React.js, MySQL and webpack (also the errors and your research findings). Well, **was your original question resolved**? (I mean, using `import styles from './stylecs.css'` helped fixing the error mentioned in this question?)

Comment: Actually I don't have any problem with the statement "require('./stylecs.css');". The program runs fine. When I am trying to add the statement "import mysql from 'mysql';" or "var mysql  = require('mysql');" to store the data into MySQL server, the error in the screenshot are shown.

Comment: what bundling tool are you using? Please post the configuration code.

Comment: I am using webpack. I posted the code related to the config file  "webpack.config.in" above. I also posted the package.json code.